# Bad operand type for unary-:"str'

Tags: python

New to Python and can't figure out what's wrong with the code below.

```
a = input('input a number: ')
if int(a) >=0:
    print(a)
else:
    print(-a)
```

When enter -2, the output should be 2.

However, I got a error code:

```
TypeError: bad operand type for unary-:"str' on print(-a)
```

Can anyone help? Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

try:

```
a = int(input('input a number: '))
if a >=0:
    print(a)
else:
    print(-a)
```

or

```
a = int(input('input a number: '))
print abs(a)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
a = input('input a number: ')
#a at this point is a string, not an integer
if int(a) >=0:
    print(a)
    #you are printing a string, it just happen to look the same as an integer
else:
    print(-int(a))
    #you could do - to an integer, not a string
```

Answer (score -1):

In case you are dealing with a string:

```
replace int with str

print(str(a))
```

Comment: This adds nothing that the previous answers don't cover in more detail, and isn't even runnable code (comment isn't a comment)